# Query para pegar palavra apos determinado caractere

Tags: sql, sql-server

Bom dia,
Preciso de uma forma para pegar todo o restante de uma string apos determinado caractere, por exemplo, tenho a seguinte base de dados
[image: Base de dados]

Preciso buscar sempre o que resta da string apos o ultimo **"»"** ou seja, para a primeira linha eu precisava pegar todo **"Acesso ao sistema"** pois não tem **"»"**

Na segunda row preciso pegar **"Farmácia Popular"** pois está apos o o ULTIMO **"»"**

Até o momento tenho a seguinte query

```
select TOP 10 COUNT(SolID) as soma, SolCaminho as caminho
from Solicitacao where
DATEPART(m, SolData) = DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, 0, getdate()))
AND DATEPART(yyyy, SolData) = DATEPART(yyyy, DATEADD(m, 0, getdate()))
and UsuIDGrupoRespConclusao = 2655
group by SolCaminho order by soma desc
```

Tentei fazer com SUBSTRING com CharIndex porém não tive sucesso.

Comment: Use `substring` e `charindex` direito que dá certo

Comment: Você poderia dar mais detalhes sobre a estrutura do seu banco de dados? Como é essa tabela `Solicitacao`?

Comment: Você quer buscar o "FIM" aonde? No SolCaminho?

Comment: Amigos, refiz a pergunta...

Comment: Posta na pergunta como ficou a query depois das alterações

Comment: Alguma resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Answer (score 4):

Você não informou qual palavra deseja comparar nem de qual coluna buscar, adapte e teste:

```
with t as (SELECT 'Inicio bla bla bla Meio bla Fim bla ww Fim 123 bla dihfidfh' as teste)

select SUBSTRING(teste, (len(teste) - CHARINDEX(REVERSE('Fim'), REVERSE(teste)) - 1), len(teste)) FROM t
```

Editado... novamente, incluí um `CASE`:

```
select TOP 10 COUNT(SolID) as soma,
        CASE WHEN SolCaminho LIKE '% >> %'
                THEN SUBSTRING(SolCaminho, (len(SolCaminho) - CHARINDEX(REVERSE('>> '), REVERSE(SolCaminho)) + 2), len(SolCaminho))
                ELSE SolCaminho
           END as caminho
from Solicitacao where
DATEPART(m, SolData) = DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, 0, getdate()))
AND DATEPART(yyyy, SolData) = DATEPART(yyyy, DATEADD(m, 0, getdate()))
and UsuIDGrupoRespConclusao = 2655
group by CASE WHEN SolCaminho LIKE '% >> %'
                THEN SUBSTRING(SolCaminho, (len(SolCaminho) - CHARINDEX(REVERSE('>> '), REVERSE(SolCaminho)) + 2), len(SolCaminho))
                ELSE SolCaminho
           END
order by soma desc
```

Note que usei a função no `group by` também, agrupar depois de tratar, se necessário use:

```
group by SolCaminho
```

Comment: Amigo, refiz a pergunta... não consegui dessa forma

Comment: Não deu certo cara, retornou os nomes inteiros

Answer (score 2):

Estava pesquisando sobre CHARINDEX pela internet e acabei aqui, então tentei
buscar uma solução pro problema visto que aparentemente não foi resolvido.

REVERSE para inverter os caracteres e CHARINDEX para pegar a posição do '>>'.
Com isso pego o último '>>' da frase, logo depois a função RIGHT
para retornar a parte da direita da frase com o número de caracteres especificado no CHARINDEX...

LTRIM() retira os espaços a esquerda!

Não sou tão bom com explicações, qualquer coisa, teste CADA FUNÇÃO do exemplo abaixo e veja como funciona.

Exemplo 1:

```
SELECT LTRIM(RIGHT('Faturamento >> Cupom Fiscal', CHARINDEX('>>', REVERSE('Faturamento >> Cupom Fiscal'))-1))
```

Exemplo 2:

```
SELECT LTRIM(RIGHT('Faturamento >> Cupom Fiscal >> Farmácia Popular', CHARINDEX('>>', REVERSE('Faturamento >> Cupom Fiscal >> Farmácia Popular'))-1))
```

Comment: Acredito que a sua resposta seja a melhor nessa pergunta até então, por isso gostaria de sugerir que você adicionasse uma explicação à solução, tornando-a melhor ainda

Answer (score 1):

Tente assim:

```
select substring('começo;meio#fim',
         charindex('#', 'começo;meio#fim') + 1, len('começo;meio#fim')
       )
  from tabela;
```

> Veja funcionando aqui no [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/087768/2).

Comment: Se tiver duas palavras iguais, no seu caso **fim**, pega a partir da primeira, isso não é um problema ?

Comment: @TiagoOliveiradeFreitas se tivesse duas palavras iguais é só delimitar elas com caracteres especiais. Qual outra forma seria possível ?

Comment: Da para usar o ```REVERSE``` na coluna e na palavra a comparar, mas no caso se ele sabe que só vem uma vez a palavra ou sabe quantas vezes esta virá sua resposta é a ideal, ficou mais limpo o código.

Comment: @TiagoOliveiradeFreitas Bacana... Vou testar sua resposta depois, não conhecia este método!

Comment: Amigos, refiz a pergunta... não consegui dessa forma

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar uma função de separação e pegar a última parte da sequência:

```
SELECT (SELECT TOP(1) sep.item
          FROM separacao(s.solcaminho, ' >> ') sep
         ORDER BY sep.sequencia DESC) AS solcaminho
  FROM solicitacao s;
```

O código da função utilizada é o seguinte:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('separacao', 'TF') IS NULL
BEGIN
  EXEC('CREATE FUNCTION separacao() RETURNS @partes TABLE(t INT) AS BEGIN RETURN END');
END;
go

ALTER FUNCTION separacao(@frase       VARCHAR(MAX),
                         @delimitador VARCHAR(MAX) = ',')

RETURNS @partes TABLE (item      VARCHAR(MAX),
                       sequencia INTEGER)

BEGIN
  DECLARE @parte     VARCHAR(MAX)
  DECLARE @sequencia INTEGER

  SET @sequencia = 0;

  WHILE CHARINDEX(@delimitador, @frase, 0) <> 0
  BEGIN
    SET @parte = SUBSTRING(@frase, 1, CHARINDEX(@delimitador, @frase, 0) - 1);
    SET @frase = SUBSTRING(@frase, CHARINDEX(@delimitador, @frase, 0) + LEN(REPLACE(@delimitador, ' ', '_')), LEN(@frase));

    IF LEN(@parte) > 0
    BEGIN
      INSERT INTO @partes(item, sequencia)
      VALUES(@parte, @sequencia + 1);

      SET @sequencia = @sequencia + 1;
    END;
  END;

  IF LEN(@frase) > 0
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @partes(item, sequencia)
    VALUES(@frase, @sequencia + 1);
  END;

  RETURN;
END;
go
```

[**Aqui**](https://github.com/Sorackb/StackOverflowPT/blob/master/MSSQL/Programabilidade/separacao.sql) está o código da função utilizada e [**aqui**](https://github.com/Sorackb/StackOverflowPT/blob/master/MSSQL/Query%20para%20pegar%20palavra%20apos%20determinado%20caractere%20(97102).sql) você confere o `script` para testar a resposta.

Answer (score 0):

No meu caso o sistema tem um campo endereço onde fica o endereço e número tudo junto, eu precisava separar o número e resolvi assim

```
SELECT CASE WHEN endereco LIKE '%,%'
            THEN SUBSTRING( RTRIM(LTRIM(endereco)), CHARINDEX(',', RTRIM(LTRIM(endereco)), 5) +1, 5)
            ELSE ''
       END as 'ENDEREÇO' FROM tabela
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

eu tive um problema semelhante e precisava ficar com a parte da string á direita do '_' e fiz assim

```
select SUBSTRING(coluna2,charindex('_',coluna2)+1,CHARINDEX('_',REVERSE(coluna2))) as coluna2
```

assim ao inverter a string fiquei com tudo á direita do '_' espero ter ajudado

Comment: Considere ser explicativo e detalhista em suas respostas.

Answer (score -1):

Estava com a mesma duvida, precisava exibir apenas a extensão (.xls, .doc ...) mas havia strings que continham o ponto no meio do nome (nome.do.arquivo.xls).

O CHARINDEX não funcionou para mim, mas consegui obter o resultado utilizando o REVERSE e POSITION

meu name_filter:  texto.texto.xls

```
SELECT distinct 
REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(name_filter), 1, POSITION('.' IN REVERSE(name_filter)) - 1)) AS last_words_after_dot

FROM your_table
```

a saída ficou:  .xls

espero ter ajudado alguém.