# MYSQL - select que retorna tudo que tenha antes de uma '-' ou '/'

Tags: mysql, sql-select

tenho uma coluna na minha tabela 'RG_ORGAO' e lá vamos encontrar linhas preenchidas assim:

SSP - SECRETARIA DE SEGURANÇA PÚBLICA

DGPC - DIRETORIA GERAL DE POLICIA CIVIL

DETRAN - DEPARTAMENTO DE TRANSITO

preciso fazer um select que me retorne tudo que contem antes da '-'

Comment: Pode dar uma olhada, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/97102/query-para-pegar-palavra-apos-determinado-caractere espero que ajude

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Retorne a substring antes da primeira ocorrência do delimitador "-":

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('foo-bar-bar', '-', 1) as result;
```

Outputs result = "foo"

Comment: Obrigado deu certo aqui..

mais uma pergunta posso usar mais de uma vez na mesma coluna?

Comment: Como assim mais de uma vez na coluna? ele não altera o dado, então podes usar infinitas vezes.

Comment: SUBSTRING_INDEX SEPEARA NUM VETOR E VOCÊ DETERMINA O CAMPO DE SEPARAÇÃO, NO CASO O "-"    SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(RG_ORGAO, "-", 1);